# What is the requirement for a server on SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql-server

I'm sorry if this question is a bit too vague, but I haven't really done anything with SQL Server.  I downloaded the Management Studio, and it's asking me for a server location.  I need to host the database somewhere so that it can be accessed by many computers (am I right about this???), so I opened a free account on 000webhost.com.  I just wanted to know: could I use this as a server to host on?

Comment: Just few hours earlier: http://stackoverflow.com/q/43257209/2224701

Answer (score 0):

First: I don't think that this is what you're implying, but SQL Server Management Studio is completely separate from the server software itself.

With that said, you have the option of either using an external host or using your local machine. I'm not familiar with 000webhost.com offhand, but you can confirm with them whether you're able to do that (it's more of a host policy than a technical limitation).

For development purposes, it doesn't really matter where you put it (as long as it's somewhere you have unrestricted access to). For your actual production server, it'll obviously have to be set up to be available to whatever computer(s) need it. Whether that entails your database server being publically available or not really depends on what you're trying to do; if you're hosting a web site or web service, for example, then only your web service or web site need to be publically available - you only need to make the database server available to the server hosting the web site. (They could even be the same server - either way, no one but the web site needs to have direct access to the database).

You may also want to consider using an Amazon Web Services or Microsoft Azure (cloud computing) account depending on what you're trying to do.

**TL;DR** Odds are you *don't* want to make your database publically available - presumably, most people won't be querying your database directly, they'll be accessing it indirectly through a web site or web service. In that case, make the web site/service public-facing and just give access to the web site and any developers you happen to be working with.