# To read a huge html content extracted from SQL*Plus Report

Tags: sql, database, ssms

A html file, when it's opened by Chrome browser, the tab shows "SQL*Plus Report".

First line of the content is "SQL> @file_name.txt". The main content is a table alike with rows and columns.

It's a huge file of size about 10 gigabytes. Chrome browser keeps loading never finished and finally crashed.

The data looks like a data base, so I think of SSMS could be a tool.

The goal is to use the data for analysis. It's ideal can be export (at least a portion of it) to Excel.

I am thinking if Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio is right tool to open this file.

Referencing to [How to connect to a local database in SQL Server Management Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43257209/how-to-connect-to-a-local-database-in-sql-server-management-studio), I followed as Open SSMS -> Connect, and for the server name type: (LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB, and choose Windows Authentication to Connect.

It gives an error as below:

(Installed Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 18. I tried to search any file named with "LocalDb" but returns null - is this the reason?)

[image]

What is the proper way to open this huge html file? Thank you.

Comment: Sounds to me more like a capable text editor that will read into memory only a small part of the file at a time  (I know UltraEdit has this feature) is the way to go, but you haven't said what you actually want to DO with your file so we can't say what is "proper". It's an HTML file, it's just marked up text, it's kinda obvious why you might want to open it in chrome ("to look at it"), but you give no clue as to why you think it's a good idea to open it in SSMS. Can you explain what your ultimate goal is with this file?

Comment: @CaiusJard, thank you for the comment. I's like a data base, so I think SSMS could be used to query it .

I want to perform analysis from this data. It's ideal that it can be exported (at least a portion of it) to Excel.